# Java vs C | Passing objects as argumens

Tags: java, c, class, object, constructor

Recently I've started to learn C and I'm confused by this thing here ->

I had a program in Java which was reading a file and counting words in it. Now I'm trying to re-write it in C.

So, in Java I had this:

class with main() method

```
...
File words = new File("AV1611Bible.txt");
WordReader wr = new WordReader(words);
...
```

and next to the constructor in the WR class

```
   private static final int READING_WHITESPACE = 11;
   ...

   private int state;
   private BufferedReader reader;

   public WordReader(File words)
   {
      state = READING_WHITESPACE;
      try
      {
         reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(words));
      }
      catch (FileNotFoundException e)
      {
      }
   }
```

Everything is initialized and can be used.

Now in C it is:

(main class)

```
     ...
     FILE* file;
     char* fileToRead = "toRead.txt";
     file = fopen(fileToRead, "r");

     WordReader* reader = createWordReader(file);
     ...
```

Now what confuses me is what exactly I need to do with this FILE object in the WR constructor.

(header file for WR)

```
typedef struct _WordReader
{
   int state;
   FILE* file;
} WordReader;

WordReader* createWordReader(FILE* fileToRead);
...
```

(WordReader.c)

```
    WordReader* createWordReader(FILE* fileToRead)
    {
            WordReader* reader = malloc(sizeof(WordReader));
            reader -> state = READING_WHITESPACE;
            //-----------------
            reader -> file; // What to do with it?
            //-----------------
            // reader -> file = fopen(fileToRead, "r"); Maybe? I've tried like this but   
all I get is a bunch of errors.
            //-----------------
       return reader;
    }
```

Comment: AFAIK you don't have classes in `C` , you have structs, no objects no constructors or destructors.. just assign `reader->file = fileToRead;`

Comment: @nachokk I'm still not used with C terms. Java keeps on popping out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your main class, you already used `fopen` to get a file handle for the file you want to read from, and you passed it as an argument to `createWordReader`. You probably just want to save the file handle in the WordReader struct, so that you can use it in future calls to `fread` when you want to read data from the file.

```
reader->file = fileToRead;
```

Comment: Yes, now that you pointed at it. It was pretty obvious if I think about it. I'm still not used with C, quite confusing after switching from Java.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for this:

```
reader -> file = fileToRead;
```